# how to connect to mongo replica cluster which is ssl/tls enabled?

Tags: ssl, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have three mongo instance(Replicaset) with ssl/tls i.e I have 3 pair of key and cert. Which pair should be used in the Node js connection string ? Is there a way to add all 3 key&crt pair. I followed this doc to upgrade cluster to tls/ssl https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-cluster-to-ssl/